# CMSs & ERPs for hospital management system

Tags: cms

**What are the best free CMSs or CMS plugins or ERPs or any other free tools available for developing a hospital management system?**

I want to develop it for a children's hospital run by my father. The hospital is small with two doctors. Currently, everything is done manually on paper. The main entities who will be using the system are: Receptionist, the two doctors, chemist and the medical laboratorist. They will use it majorly for keeping the records of the patient. The patients would not be interacting with the system directly. The system needs to be user friendly and should be easy to learn.
I was thinking to develop such a system using a CMS or an ERP or any other free tool. I have used wordpress/drupal in past but never used an ERP. Can you please guide me to make such a system using free, and preferably open source, tools?

Thanks,
Akshey

Answer (score 1):

SugarCRM may be an option. Contact information is fairly easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Medical](http://medical.sourceforge.net/) a Health and Hospital Information System. Is it open source, and I suspect it could be very close to what you are looking for. If not, maybe you could use OpenERP, a very interesting open source ERP. As Medical, it is based on the python framework OpenObject. It is very flexible, and it is so easy to develop new modules.

Comment: I actually posted the same thing only to realize that this reply has already been put. You can also look at Practo (its a paid software) which is a market leader for Dentists in India.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find such type of software free but you should order to software companies to create a such software that can give you self satisfaction.